# universal windows application Bluetooth support

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth, uwp, rfcomm

I have tried RFCOMM API to send image(jpeg) from UWP (on windows tablet) to other mobile(any mobile android / windows ).

In my app, socket creation is success and writing to socket outputstream gives the value of file size as return value ( Think it's also success ).

But at the receiver side it's not showing any accept/receive and can't see the file in that device.

I have also added capability in app manifest.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.rfcomm">
    <Device Id="any">
        <Function Type="serviceId:00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" />
    </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

C# code:

```
async void Initialize()
{
    var services = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
    RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
        RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));

    if (services.Count > 0)
    {
        var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(services[0].Id);

        if (SupportsProtection(service))
        {
            _service = service;

            Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessStatus accessStatus = await _service.Device.RequestAccessAsync();

            if (accessStatus.Equals(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceAccessStatus.DeniedByUser))
            {
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
                return;
            }

            dialog = new MessageDialog(_service.Device.Name);
            await dialog.ShowAsync();

            _socket = new StreamSocket();
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(_service.ConnectionHostName, _service.ConnectionServiceName, SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

            var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
            picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
            picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
            PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)stream.Length];
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                IBuffer buffer = bytes.AsBuffer();
                uint test = await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
                await _socket.OutputStream.FlushAsync();
                _socket.Dispose();

                dialog = new MessageDialog("Result :" + test.ToString());
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I didn't see the code of your receiver side, it's hard to say why you can't receive image files. To send and receive images, you can refer to [**Bluetooth RFCOMM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/send-or-receive-files-with-rfcomm). This document contains example code about how to send or receive a file with Bluetooth RFCOMM. Although there are some teeny mistakes in the example code, but we can fix them easily. And the following is a simple sample uses the example code and demonstrates how to send and receive image files.

**Send image file as a client**

```
private RfcommDeviceService _service;
private StreamSocket _socket;

private async void Initialize()
{
    // Enumerate devices with the object push service
    var services =
        await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(
            RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(
                RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush));

    if (services.Count > 0)
    {
        // Initialize the target Bluetooth BR device
        var service = await RfcommDeviceService.FromIdAsync(services[0].Id);

        // Check that the service meets this App's minimum requirement
        if (SupportsProtection(service) && await IsCompatibleVersion(service))
        {
            _service = service;

            // Create a socket and connect to the target
            _socket = new StreamSocket();
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(
                _service.ConnectionHostName,
                _service.ConnectionServiceName,
                SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

            // The socket is connected. At this point the App can wait for
            // the user to take some action, e.g. click a button to send a
            // file to the device, which could invoke the Picker and then
            // send the picked file. The transfer itself would use the
            // Sockets API and not the Rfcomm API, and so is omitted here for
            // brevity.
        }
    }
}

// This App requires a connection that is encrypted but does not care about
// whether its authenticated.
private bool SupportsProtection(RfcommDeviceService service)
{
    switch (service.ProtectionLevel)
    {
        case SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket:
            if ((service.MaxProtectionLevel == SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionWithAuthentication)
                || (service.MaxProtectionLevel == SocketProtectionLevel
                    .BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication))
            {
                // The connection can be upgraded when opening the socket so the
                // App may offer UI here to notify the user that Windows may
                // prompt for a PIN exchange.
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // The connection cannot be upgraded so an App may offer UI here
                // to explain why a connection won't be made.
                return false;
            }
        case SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionWithAuthentication:
            return true;

        case SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication:
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// This App relies on CRC32 checking available in version 2.0 of the service.
private const uint SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 0x0300;

private const byte SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 0x0A;   // UINT32
private const uint MINIMUM_SERVICE_VERSION = 200;

private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> IsCompatibleVersion(RfcommDeviceService service)
{
    var attributes = await service.GetSdpRawAttributesAsync(Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
    var attribute = attributes[SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID];
    var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(attribute);

    // The first byte contains the attribute' s type
    byte attributeType = reader.ReadByte();
    if (attributeType == SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE)
    {
        // The remainder is the data
        uint version = reader.ReadUInt32();
        return version >= MINIMUM_SERVICE_VERSION;
    }
    return false;
}

// Click a button to send a image file to the device
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation =
    PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        DataWriter writer = null;
        try
        {
            writer = new DataWriter(_socket.OutputStream);

            writer.WriteUInt32((uint)file.Name.Length);
            writer.WriteString(file.Name);

            var buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
            writer.WriteUInt32(buffer.Length);
            writer.WriteBuffer(buffer);

            await writer.StoreAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        writer.DetachStream();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Receive image file as a Server**

```
private StreamSocket _socket;
private RfcommServiceProvider _provider;

private async void Initialize()
{
    // Initialize the provider for the hosted RFCOMM service
    _provider = await RfcommServiceProvider.CreateAsync(RfcommServiceId.ObexObjectPush);

    // Create a listener for this service and start listening
    StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    listener.ConnectionReceived += OnConnectionReceivedAsync;
    await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(
        _provider.ServiceId.AsString(),
        SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication);

    // Set the SDP attributes and start advertising
    InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(_provider);
    _provider.StartAdvertising(listener);
}

private const uint SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID = 0x0300;
private const byte SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = 0x0A;   // UINT32
private const uint SERVICE_VERSION = 200;

private void InitializeServiceSdpAttributes(RfcommServiceProvider provider)
{
    var writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter();

    // First write the attribute type
    writer.WriteByte(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE);
    // Then write the data
    writer.WriteUInt32(SERVICE_VERSION);

    var data = writer.DetachBuffer();
    provider.SdpRawAttributes.Add(SERVICE_VERSION_ATTRIBUTE_ID, data);
}

private async void OnConnectionReceivedAsync(
           StreamSocketListener listener,
           StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // Stop advertising/listening so that we're only serving one client
    _provider.StopAdvertising();
    listener.Dispose();
    _socket = args.Socket;

    // The client socket is connected. At this point the App can wait for
    // the user to take some action, e.g. click a button to receive a file
    // from the device, which could invoke the Picker and then save the
    // received file to the picked location. The transfer itself would use
    // the Sockets API and not the Rfcomm API, and so is omitted here for
    // brevity.

    var reader = new DataReader(_socket.InputStream);
    bool remoteDisconnection = false;

    // Infinite read buffer loop
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Based on the protocol we've defined, the first uint is the size of the file name
            uint readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));

            // Check if the size of the data is expected (otherwise the remote has already terminated the connection)
            if (readLength < sizeof(uint))
            {
                remoteDisconnection = true;
                break;
            }

            var nameLength = reader.ReadUInt32();

            readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(nameLength);

            // Check if the size of the data is expected (otherwise the remote has already terminated the connection)
            if (readLength < nameLength)
            {
                remoteDisconnection = true;
                break;
            }

            var fileName = reader.ReadString(nameLength);

            // The second uint is the size of the file
            readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));

            // Check if the size of the data is expected (otherwise the remote has already terminated the connection)
            if (readLength < sizeof(uint))
            {
                remoteDisconnection = true;
                break;
            }
            var fileLength = reader.ReadUInt32();

            readLength = await reader.LoadAsync(fileLength);

            // Check if the size of the data is expected (otherwise the remote has already terminated the connection)
            if (readLength < fileLength)
            {
                remoteDisconnection = true;
                break;
            }

            var buffer = reader.ReadBuffer(fileLength);

            // Save the received image file to local folder
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(file, buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            break;
        }
    }

    reader.DetachStream();
    reader.Dispose();
    if (remoteDisconnection)
    {
        _socket.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Please note above sample is just for demonstration, it may have unhandled exceptions. For more information, please refer to [**Bluetooth RFCOMM chat sample**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat).

Comment: i don't like to write any receiver . i  just wanted to send files to any device which is connected . like my windows tablet to any mobile ( android or windows ).